# Python Django UNIQUE constraint failed problem

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I am using the **Django REST Framework**. I want to register a new user but I always get this "error":

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: user_account.username
```

Even if I haven't the user created yet I get this error. This is my model:

```py
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
```

If I remove `unique=True` I won't get this error, but a username can exists like 5 times. That isn't what I want

## Edit

If a user really exists with this username I get what I want:

```
{"username":["account with this username already exists."]}
```

Comment: Have you checked the database? There must be user with same username already which is why you get this error

Comment: Yeah. I already deleted the database and reinstalled everything. I still get this error :/

Comment: For some reason username is duplicated. Either in db or while u are sending it from form or viewset. You have to check what you are sending as post payload

Comment: Oh yeah. Thank you :) I inserted the username twice. Can you Post this as an Answere and I mark it? :)

Comment: Haha Sure . glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unique validation in your code :

```
username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
```

So whenever a duplicate username is detected by the database, it will throw this error.
Make sure you are not sending the same username in your post payload.